# jqm dialog bug on android phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, dialog

I'm using jqm with phonegap to build an android app.
On a search page I open dialog box to choose from a list of option but on android (tested with version 2.x and  4.x) when i click an option from the box the click event is passed through the dialog and gets to the parent page, so the dialog closes and reopen again!
Has anyone ever had the same problem?

Comment: Please post your code and take a look http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ;)

Comment: here's an example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y9sZ4/1/